# Set the floating value on rating bar like 1.2

Tags: android

How i set the 1.2 rating on the rating bar. I am not able to set the 1.2 value on the rating bar if i set rating.setRating(1.2f) then it does not show any thing on the rating bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set the value on the rating bar like 1.2 , for that you have to set the step size if the rating bar 0.1 .

Answer (score 2):

Have you try this.

```
float ratingValue = 1.5f;
myRatingBar.setRating(ratingValue); // to set rating value
myRatingBar.setStepSize(ratingValue);// to show to stars
```

[Look at this tutorial](http://a2zandroidtutorials.blogspot.in/2012/07/rating-bar-events.html) for more details.

**Edit :** Sets the step size (granularity) of this rating bar. 
The step size of this rating bar. For example, if half-star granularity is wanted, this would be 0.5.

Comment: Chirag Your link is not working and this is not solution it shows the blank star. Ok

Comment: @VivekKumar Link is working properly . http://a2zandroidtutorials.blogspot.in/2012/07/rating-bar-events.html

Answer (score -1):

Try fixing values programmatically like this:

```
float ratingValue = 1.5f;
myRatingBar.setRating(ratingValue); // to set rating value
myRatingBar.setStepSize(ratingValue); // to show to stars
```